# Connecting to Redis from localhost

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I am using ElastiCache for Redis on AWS. But, I'm not able to connect to Redis from localhost. I have used the endpoint on AWS. It always shows connection timed out. Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should make sure is the VPC Security Group that the Elasticache Redis is attached, allows Custom TCP traffic from your address to port number 6379 (default for Redis).

For me the connection timed out issue arised due to the inaccessibility to the VPC where the Redis cluster resides.

Answer (score 0):

Check your security group of Elastic cache cluster. It should allow port 6379 from the EC2 instance. You can allow your EC2 instance's security group in Elastic cache security group to access port 6379.

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect AWS ElastiCache Redis outside of your VPC network or from your laptop. You have to go through tunnel to connect redis from your laptop.

As elaticache redis is not avaiable to outside network that's why you are getting timeout error because redis couldn't find the aws elasicache host.

You can easily connect to aws elaticache redis with in aws vpc, without any timeout error.

My suggestion is use your localhost to connect redis in your laptop for development and use aws elasticache redis host/port to connect inside aws server.